# how do you search/access users data?

Tags: firebase

I want to alert users who are registering that their choice of email address is already in our userbase; how can I compare their (desired) email to the users in my user list before (while) they register? Where exactly are the users stored and how can I access taht datanode?

Comment: Thanks for asking this; I just came to Firebase from Parse and was wondering the same thing. It's too bad we are unable to authenticate with only usernames (need to use an email or there's no way to have your user reset their password).

Answer (score 6):

You should have a users node that contains your users and other info about them.

Login credentials are stored internally in firebase so you don't have direct access so them. Having a users node allows access to other data about the user (and can double check to see if an email address is already in use).

```
users
  uid_00001
    name: "Frank"
    email: "frank@wazmo.com"
    fav_movie: "Airplane"
  uid_00002
    name: "Kato"
    email: "kato@yipee.com"
    fav_movie: "Pink Panther"
```

Using the above structure, you can simply query for the email address and if there's a match don't allow them to use it.

This is very common practice and there's a lot of information about handling users on the Firebase website.

Check out Storing User Data in this link

[https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html](http://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html)

Note: 7 years later... When attempting to create a user with an email that already exists, Firebase will return an error indicating the email is in use, to which you can handle the error in that fashion.

That's probably a better option than querying a users node per above as that would require giving access to it for unauthenticated users.