# How do I retrieve the list of authenticated user in my firebase account

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app that uses Email and Password Authentication. I would like to download the list of registered users so I can get their email addresses. I have a simple python script that tries to do this but it does not work because the user table is not available through the usual query means (i.e. Firebase says that user info is stored outside of your apps data). 
I can see all my user's and their emails addresses in the Firebase console but I'd like a way to automatically pull down all my user's email's. 
Is this possible?

I realize in hindsight, that I should store their emails on my own 'profile' endpoint and I can do this moving forward. But my question is how to I get the existing ones.

My python script for this.

```
def get_users():

    authentication = firebase.FirebaseAuthentication(FIREBASE_SECRET, FIREBASE_EMAIL, True, True)
    conn = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://rasphi.firebaseio.com', authentication)

    result = conn.get('/users', None)
    print result # Comes back as None

get_users()
```

Comment: You will need to store the user data in *your* Firebase database when the users log in. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737009/how-do-you-search-access-users-data/33738253#33738253 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password/14676121#14676121

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, that's what I was afraid of, I'll have to change my app to do this in the future and I guess I'll manually have to copy my current users emails.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168973/how-to-programmatically-get-the-list-of-registered-users-in-firebase