# Is there any easy way to get all e-mail of subscribed users in FireBase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We need to send an e-mail too all of our users registered using Firebase authentication. Is there any easy way to do it ? f not is there any easy option to export all their e-mail adresses ?

Comment: You can do a regex search and list all email addresses

Comment: There is currently no API to get a list of users from Firebase Authentication. Most developers store a list of users in the Firebase Database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168973/how-to-get-the-list-of-registered-user-in-firebase