# How to access in android the users registered in Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am creating an android app integrated with Firebase as the backend. I used Firebase Authentication for the authentication and management of users. I also used Firestore for the database. In my app, there will be a data(collection) named LoanRecord with the fields of lender and borrower. These 2 fields will contain user data (like foreign key in SQL database). Every time a user will create a LoanRecord data, the app will need to fetch the available users, so that the user can select and set it to the lender and borrower fields.

Now how can I fetch all the users to my android app? I do not have my own backend, so I cannot use the Firebase Admin SDK. I also don't want to use the cloud functions because apparently it's not free (this app is only for my personal use so I don't want to spend money for it).

Comment: For sure there is. Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Are you using Java or Kotlin?

Comment: I'm using kotlin. I've included my database structure above

Comment: Please edit your question and add your real database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you indicate not wanting to use Cloud Functions, the solution would be to have each user write their own user data to the database when they register/sign-in.

You can then refer to that information in the database when you need it.

This has been covered quite a few times before already, so I recommend checking out:

- [How do I return a list of users if I use the Firebase simple username & password authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password)
- [How to programmatically get the list of registered users in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168973/how-to-programmatically-get-the-list-of-registered-users-in-firebase)
- And more from these [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D%5Bandroid%5D+list+of+users)