# Access facebook user information when logged in from Firebase eg user id, name, profile picture etc

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my app, I log users in with Facebook via Firebase and each new user is created within the firebase realtime database accordingly. When signing in, users give me access to their public profile information. How can I access this information and add it to the list of properties stored within each user in the database?

Eg, when a user logs in, a new user is created in the database (already working) with their facebook username (eg facebook.com/xxxx), full name, email etc all stored as separate values within the user (no idea how to do this even after reading the docs).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you are asking how to [Save other user attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112107/how-can-i-create-a-user-with-multiple-attributes-in-firebase-with-swift/35114490#35114490) in firebase?

Comment: More than just adding properties to a user, I'm trying to add the facebook account properties of the logged in user to the database eg Name, email, username etc from Facebook, not just by entering user data @Jay

Comment: Once your authenticated to Firebase you will then have secure access to Facebook APIs. You would use the Facebook API to get to the data within Facebook you're interested in. See [Facebook Authentication API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)

Comment: Thanks @Jay, I will have a read!