# Firebase Realtime database access to some specific users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an android app in which I want to provide access to realtime database to some specific/selected users only! 
I don't know how to manage the users for that if anyone know it let me know.

I'm developing an android app in which I want to provide access to realtime database to some specific/selected users only! 
I don't know how to manage the users for that if anyone know it let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Example:

I have database in firebase as shown in this Image.

[image: Sample database]

Now, I want to provide Questions node access to only those who has onBoard value true at node Participants/$participantId/onBoard.

**if you need more info let me know!

now

Thanks in advance.

Comment: need more information, is it for giving access to your project or only to some node?

Comment: What's your platform? Did you go through the [Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides/) guide as there's some nifty examples there. Also, did you check the [Authentication Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users)? It directly addresses your questions with examples and code. Oh - and there are dozens, if not hundreds of examples here on SO regarding handling [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112107/how-can-i-create-a-user-with-multiple-attributes-in-firebase-with-swift/35114490#35114490) in Firebase.

Comment: Got it!, Thanks