# How to query user details from uid?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase database to query "Products". I am trying to also query the details of the user that uploaded the product. How can I achieve this?

Here is how users upload Product. (I save uid as they upload):

```
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.productImage.image!, 0.4)


    self.productImg = UIImage(data: imageData!)!



    let productImgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(productImg, 0.4)


    let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid


    let productImageRef = storageRef.child("ProductImages/\(uid!)/productImage.jpg")
    productImageRef.putData(productImgData!, metadata: nil) {
        metadata, error in

        if error != nil {

            print("Error occurred!")

        } else {


            let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            let post : [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["uid" : uid!,
                        "productTitle" : self.titleLabel.text!,
                        "price" : self.priceLabel.text!,
                        "description" : self.descriptionLabel.text!,
                        "productImage" : downloadURL!]

          databaseRef.child("Products").childByAutoId().setValue(post)


        }
```

And here is how I query the products:

```
struct post {
    let title : String!
    let price : String!
    let description : String!
    let image : String!
}


 let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        databaseRef.child("Products").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
            snapshot in

            print(snapshot)


            let title = snapshot.value!["productTitle"] as! String
            let price = snapshot.value!["price"] as! String
            let description = snapshot.value!["description"] as! String
            let image = snapshot.value!["productImage"] as! String

            self.posts.insert(post(title: title, price: price, description: description, image: image), atIndex: 0)

            self.homeTableView.reloadData()
            self.homeCollectionView.reloadData()


        })
```

So basically, how can I query username/profileImage based on user's uid?

[image]

Comment: There is no public API in Firebase Authentication to get information about another user. Each user can only access their own properties. Most developer store a list of users in the Firebase Database, so that they can then query it as needed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737009/how-do-you-search-access-users-data

Comment: Okay, I will just leave those out for now. Thanks!